# Odoo 12 NonType errors on custom report

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I am trying to create a custom report under **Odoo 12** to be added to the print option under Orders View. So far, so good, I include the XML in the manifest and create the XML under the sale_management/report folder. I update the module upon editing and it is compiled right. Nevertheless, once I hit the print button, I get this error:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 347, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_829_149
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_148
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1671, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1612, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 712, in render_qweb_pdf
    html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 752, in render_qweb_html
    return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 534, in render_template
    return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1304, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 27, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1313, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 59, in render
    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 275, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 354, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 347, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_829_149
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_148
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'with_context'
Template: 829
Path: /templates/t/t/t[1]
Node: <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context(lang=doc.partner_id.lang)"/>
```

For testing purposes, the XML is almost verbatim of the already included template in the same directory named **sale_report_templates.xml** and my whole file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <report
            id="albaran_sin_valorar"
            string="Documento sin valorar"
            model="sale.order"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="sale_management.report_albaran_sin_valorar"
        />

<template id="report_albaran_sin_valorar" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('page')]/p[@id='fiscal_position_remark']" position="after">
        <div t-if="doc.sale_order_option_ids and doc.state in ['draft', 'sent']">
            <t t-set="has_option_discount" t-value="any(doc.sale_order_option_ids.filtered(lambda o: o.discount$
            <h4>
                <span>Optional Products</span>
            </h4>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">Description</th>
                        <th t-if="has_option_discount" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line" class="text-lef$
                        <th class="text-right">Unit Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="sale_tbody">
                    <tr t-foreach="doc.sale_order_option_ids" t-as="option">
                        <td>
                            <span t-field="option.name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td t-if="has_option_discount" groups="sale.group_discount_per_so_line">
   ...
   </template>
   </odoo>
```

My questions are:
- Of course, what is the problem.
- What are the inners of Odoo involved in the problem so I can fully understand it

Thanks in advance
Jose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to `inheriting` Default Odoo **Sale Report** but your `report action` is calling is different. On your customized report that object it not detaching['sale.order'] So instead of an object, you got none.

Simply go through the link with how to work with report inheritance [Sale-inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/).

On **XML** **File** for Sale Report Customisation,

```
<template id="report_saleorder_document_customise" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <!-- Give the xpath according to your requirement -->
    <xpath expr="//table[hasclass('o_main_table')]//tr/th[@name='th_subtotal']" position="before">
       <!-- Add your customise with give the xpath -->
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Add the **Xml file** in  `__manifest__` file.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any difference in the workflow for the 12 release?

Comment: yes, there has some features to be added on odoo12.so better you can found videos/documentation regarding odoo 12 features.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot make it work nor find correct documentation to do this. I have been more than two weeks trying to put all things together to no avail. I just want to add a second option to print de order without including prices. Following your url it is not clear how it does work, If I will just lose the original format and use the new one, why this tutorial does not show the manifest file (is it not needed?), etc... a lot of questions. I am really lost and the docs from odoo dont help me understand all the underlying mechanisms.

Comment: one thing, you have to customize the sale report than only need one XML file and add it into to manifest file.then on your XML file from the link take the code of inherit_id="sale.report_id" and with the xpath trying to modify your report. only this thing you have to do and you got the result.so please try it.

Comment: I have edited my answer, so you can follow by this.